# Name for this type of series?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using Mathematica's `Asymptotic` function I get the following identity. For $s\approx 0$ we have
$$\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{5 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \sqrt{s}}{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}\right)^{-1} \approx \sqrt{\frac{3\pi^2}{50 s}}$$

The simplified formula fits my data really well (see [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446547/upper-bound-for-an-inverse-laplace-transform)), any idea where this result comes from?

Is there a standard series expansion where the leading term is of the form $a_0 s^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: Yes you can use the expansion of $\tan^{-1}$

Comment: Plugging $\arctan(t\to+\infty)\to\pi/2$ and $s/2\to0$ gives $\approx\left(0+\frac{5\sqrt{2s/3}}{2\cdot\pi/2}\right)^{-1}$ which equals RHS.

Comment: The formal name for series with negative/fractional powers is [Puiseax series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series).